# "Create Paypal button" interface

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

When I try to create / modify a "Paypal button", I always arrive on a page that:

1. Looks the same as 10 years ago
2. Recommends to use **"Internet Explorer 7 (!), Firefox 3 or Safari 4"** for best results
3. In this button creation page, I cannot find how to choose the style among the "Custom payment page styles" created in this page: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-page-styles. What is [this page](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-page-styles) useful for, then, if we cannot use them when creating a button?

**Did I miss a new interface somewhere (URL?) for button creation or is this very old interface still up to date?**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The button creation page, which you are seeing is valid and it still appears the same.

However, the customization of the checkout page is no longer available through the Custom Payment pages( This feature is deprecated).

You may still add a logo, but that has to be done through coding. You will need to add the variable "image_url" with the value of the logo URL. For Express Checkout payments, you may use LOGOIMG .

For more details, kindly refer to this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/checkout-settings/#customizing-paypal-checkout-pages.